# Select a text before a character

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have this string:

> Test: String

And I want to select the text before the **:**, as if that were the result: "Test";

Any tip?

Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: @yuji Put it in another string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string:

```
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

Then select array's first element.

```
NSString *select = [words objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(select);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *firstWord = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks, Yuji, but Pablo answered before. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
NSString *str = @"Test: String";
NSSArray *Arrstr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:@":"];
```

Now you will have two strings in the array. Take first by :

```
NSString *str1 = [Arrstr objectatindex : 0];
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Sarah, but Pablo answered before.